# Why doesn't the StackExchange site have a "global" footer?

Tags: discussion, questions

Almost all of the other SO sites have a "global" footer that allow quick access to the other primary sites (Area51) etc. Is there any reason why SE site not follow the same implementation?

You can probably add that question to some of the other sites as well (like Area 51).

Surely this would be strengthening the network effect of your SEO.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you want here? Are you talking about the difference in the sites listed in the footer between beta and graduated SE sites?

Comment: Easiest way to explain is by looking at the bottom of this page on meta.stackoverflow.com - now look at the footer on stackexchange.com - so yes the sites listed and other related info - it seems to break the "family" or network homogeneity effect.